# Artifactory AQL download artifact

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang, jfrog-cli

Is there a way to download an artifact using AQL?

I have a query sent with:

```
curl -u user:pass \
-X POST https://artifactoryURL/artifactory/api/search/aql \
-H 'content-type: text/plain' \
-T query.aql
```

And my `query.aql`:

```
items.find(
    {
        "repo":{"$eq":"repo"},
        "$and": [
          {
            "path": { "$match": "path/*"},
            "name": { "$match": "*.rpm"}
          }
        ]
    }
)
.sort({ "$desc": ["modified"] })
.limit(1)
```

Now that I know it returns what I want, Is there a way to change the request from `api/search/aql` to something like `api/download/aql` and get those items?

**EDIT:**

I had also tried doing this with the **jfrog cli** but they don't fully support AQL there (sort and limit didn't work).

This is the command I tried:

```
jfrog rt s --spec=query-aql.json
```

And the spec that failed to sort and limit results:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "repo",
          "$and": [
            {
              "path": { "$match": "path/*"},
              "name": { "$match": "*.rpm"}
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "sort": {
        "$asc": ["modified"]
      },
      "limit": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Added a jfrog-cli-go issue: https://github.com/JFrogDev/jfrog-cli-go/issues/56

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to use your aql script to download files from artifactory is to use the JFrog cli as mention here : https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-Download,CopyandMoveCommandsSpecSchema

The cli can be downloaded as an executable for linux, mac or windows and should fit your needs

With the curl command the only thing you can do is then to parse the result from your aql query and perform download request for each file.

Comment: The jfrog cli failed to sort and limit my results (see edit). The major pain here is that for something very simple I have to have a high level language parsing the returned json when AQL should just allow me to narrow down my results to one and get that.

Answer (score 2):

I was just looking for a very similar thing -- use a download spec file to download the latest artifact from a given repo and path. I don't care if I use AQL or not, I just want it in the `download-spec.json` file. If you go to the [link](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-Download,CopyandMoveCommandsSpecSchema) above look at **Example 5**.

Modified for your example:

```
{
  "files": [
  {
    "pattern": "path/*.rpm",
    "target": "my/download/path/",
    "sortBy": "created",
    "sortOrder": "desc",
    "limit": 1,
  }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jfrog cli supports `--limit`, `--sort-order`, and `--sort-by` arguments.

The following works for me:

```
jfrog rt search --spec=/tmp/jfrogfilespec.json --sort-by created --sort-order=desc --limit 1
```

The contents of the json spec file are:

```
{ "files": [ { "aql": { "items.find": { "repo":{"$eq":"my-release-repo"}, "name":{"$match":"my-artifact-prefix*"} } } } ] }
```

This generates the following query (according to debug mode):

```
items.find( { "repo":{"$eq":"my-release-repo"}, "name":{"$match":"my-artifact-prefix*"} } ).include("name","repo","path","actual_md5","actual_sha1","size","type","created").sort({"$desc":["created"]}).limit(1)
```

What is frustrating is that I cannot seem to find a way to use "jfrog rt search" with a filespec that allows me to influence the "include" modifier portion of the search.

Comment: Please take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. As you will see, your code is not properly [marked as code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262).  Also read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to write good answers. Better answers will get you more upvotes and have a higher chance of being accepted.