# Get a list of builds with the jenkins artifactory plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=99910084

I can upload and download, but I just want to query and get a list of artifactory builds for a repo.

I want to get a list of all builds for a given repo to present it to the user so they can choose a previous build to deploy.

All I need is a list of the builds. I can do this with a rest call but I already have credentials and the server URL configured for the Jenkins plugin. would be nice to use the plugin.

How do i do this with the plugin (without having to do my own rest calls)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like it is possible yet.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47597903/jenkins-artifactory-plugin-grabbing-latest-artifacts) from a few months earlier contains a possible solution (aka workaround) where the question asker, posted their own answer.

To get the list of builds I wrote a groovy class in a shared library to return the list of version numbers and the latest version number.

Comment: Updated my question, I want a list of "builds" not artifacts. I want to present the user with a list of previous builds to choose one to download

Comment: Updated my answer.  I don't think what you want to do is supported natively.  Artifactory will direct you to the REST API currently.  Which I know you don't want but its what is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same requirement. Seems still not to be supported by the Artifactory plugin.

Therefore I wrote following small pipeline script. You'd have to run it inside some node featuring `curl`. So most probably this will need a linux node or cygwin installation.

```
String jsonData = ""
node('linux') {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '<credentials id>', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'username')]) {
        jsonData = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "curl -u '$username:$password' <url to artifactory repository>")
    }
}

def json = readJSON(text: jsonData)

List<String> deployments = []
json.children.each {
    echo it.uri
    deployments << it.uri
}
```

Having that the `deployments` variable will contain a list of artifacts available in the selected repository.